# "Cannot find type definition file for 'async'. TS2688"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, create-react-app

I have a react/typescript app made with `create-react-app`

When I try to `yarn start` in my computer i get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

undefined
TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined):
Cannot find type definition file for 'async'.  TS2688
```

I don't understand why is this error happening. Why would `async` need a type definition? And why is it not finding it?

I already tried removing `node_modules`  and `yarn.lock` and doing `yarn install``

I also tried removing the whole folder and cloning my repo again (and installing everything again).

Curiously, this works perfectly fine in my laptop when I clone the repo:

https://github.com/grochadc/filex-workshops-registration

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "typescript-react-testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "10.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase": "^7.21.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "mutation-observer": "^1.0.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-responsive": "^8.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.3",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "json-server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.24.2",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I edited the file that was giving me the async problem (I removed async) and I keep getting the same error.

Atom Linter gives me an error at the start of `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'async' .
Cannot find type definition file for 'graphql' .
Cannot find type definition file for 'isomorphic-fetch' .
```

Im stumped because I didn't add `graphql` as a dependency (it is certainly not in `package.json`).

Comment: Please add your `tsconfig.json` to the question.

Comment: If it works one one system and not another. Verify that the versions of all tools, from NodeJS on down are the same.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I checked and my laptop had Node v12 and main Computer had Node v14 but when I updated laptop to v14 still works fine (while main fails". What other tools should I check for compatibility?

Comment: Check the yarn version. Clone it to a different location on your laptop and verify that it works. It could be some types in parent directories are being picked up.

Comment: Updated Yarn to 1.22.5 and cloned everything again on both machines and still one gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

this might be related to the node version you are using the least version should be nvm 10.18, so please make sure you have the right dependencies.

Comment: I have Node v14.1.0 on both systems. What other dependencies should I check?